# Mapping values across dataframes to create a new one

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. The first represents the nutritional information of certain ingredients with ingredients as rows and the columns as the nutritional categories.

```
                                Item                    Brand and style   Quantity Calories Total Fat  ... Carbs Sugar Protein Fiber Sodium
0                         Brown rice     xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx, long grain       150g      570       4.5  ...  1170     0      12     6      0
1                  Whole wheat bread             xxxxxxxx, whole grains   2 slices      220         4  ...    42     6       8     6    320
2                 Whole wheat cereal  xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx, wheat squares        60g      220         1  ...    47     0       7     5      5
```

The second represents the type and quantity of ingredients of meals with the meals as rows and the ingredients as columns.

```
                           Meal Brown rice Whole wheat bread Whole wheat cereal  ... Marinara sauce American cheese Olive oil Salt
0            Standard breakfast          0                 0                  1  ...              0               0         0    0
1                Standard lunch          0                 2                  0  ...              0               0         0    0
2               Standard dinner          0                 0                  0  ...              0               0         1    1
```

I am trying to create another dataframe such that the meals are rows and the nutritional categories are at the top, representing the entire nutritional value of the meal based on the number of ingredients.

For example, if a standard lunch consists of 2 slices of bread (150 calories each slice), 1 serving of peanut butter (100 calories), and 1 serving of jelly (50 calories), then I would like the dataframe to be like:

```
          Meal  Calories Total fat ...
Standard lunch  450       xxx
Standard dinner xxx       xxx
...
```

450 comes from (2*150 + 100 + 50).

The function template could be:

```
def create_meal_category_dataframe(ingredients_df, meals_df):
    ingredients = meals_df.columns[1:]
    meals = meals_df['Meal']
    # return meal_cat_df
```

I extracted lists of the meal and ingredient names, but I'm not sure if they're useful here. Thanks.

Comment: Where does the data come from? Are you creating it entirely yourself?

Comment: The data is coming from a spreadsheet I created.

Comment: Alright, now I can’t remember why I asked that last night...

Comment: Could you share the data (even just a portion of it) as CSV in your post? It would make running your code much easier :) See: [mcve]. This is a cool question IMO, I would love to be able to come up with a solid answer.

Comment: Here's the meals: https://pastebin.com/TAD1DRnd
Here's the ingredients: https://pastebin.com/Ri5RAHXA

Comment: Great, I’ll take a look tomorrow :)

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: Uh I somehow completely forgot about this, sorry :/ On a positive note I have a better idea of how to solve it than last time. It is almost 1:00 for me though, so It’ll have to wait until tomorrow morning unfortunately.

Comment: Did you manage to find a way?

Comment: I think I got rid of the code I was working on, because I forgot what it was for  The pastebin expired, can you send the data again?

Comment: Ingredients: https://pastebin.com/FVxti6xL Meals: https://pastebin.com/XDQ6DxZD

Comment: I will be sure to save the data this time ;)

Comment: Did you make any progress?